# Checking that GPS is paused after turning screen off?

Tags: gps

I suspect a maps-based application I use doesn't actually pause GPS after I turn the screen off like it's supposed to, draining the battery accordingly.

Is there a way to check the status of GPS after the screen is turned off?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app may help by giving you a audio notification under the twin conditions of ( app being active, GPS being enabled ) when the screen is turned off

**Trigger:** Screen off

**Action:**

**If**

app state of your app ( choose from running in background / not in foreground / alive in background /not running- in the example below it is App in foreground)

**And**

GPS enabled

add child action of Notification sound,

**end if**

**Constraints:** None

[image]

Comment: Since you didn't link the maps app you used, I couldn't verify if GPS is running or not when screen is off